# Return in the function is working incorrect

Tags: python, list

Hey Stackoverflow community,

I am a python newbie.

So, I am trying to build the function any() from scratch. However the output I get is not what I expected. My code is working fine without the second if statement:

```
def anys(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        if bool(lst[i])==True:
            return True
```

anys([False,True,False]) executes True as expected.
However, when I am adding a second if  statement I get a different outcome:

```
def anys(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        if bool(lst[i])==True:
            return True
        if bool(lst[i])==False or len(lst)==0:
            return False
```

anys([False,True,False]) executes False.

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side-note `if bool(lst[i]) == True:` is a slow, incredibly non-idiomatic way to spell `if lst[i]:`. For that matter `for i in range(len(someseq)): # do stuff with someseq[i]` is an unidiomatic way to do `for item in someseq: # do stuff with item`. Figured you might want to learn this early before you lock in bad habits. Simplified end result if `for item in lst: if item: return True`.

Comment: thank you @ShadowRanger I will take note of that!

Comment: @Python_learner Looks like ShadowRanger and I are in agreement on these points! (See below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a return statement, the function will stop executing and, as instructed, return to the place where the function was called from. This means that the function will return at the first elemt in the list since it was `False`. If you want the function to return false if all of the elemts are false, I would recomend that you put the `return False` statement after the for loop.

To clearify, the loop starts with the first elemnt in the list, which in this case is `False`. The element satisfies the condition:

```
if bool(lst[i])==False or len(lst)==0:
```

And the function will then return False.

---

To answer the comment, if you loop through the entire list, and none of the elements are true (in other words "any"), you then want to return false instead.

```
def anys(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        if bool(lst[i])==True:
            return True
    return False
```

The code now goes through the list, if it ever encounters a `True` value, it returns True, however if none of the elements are True, it instead returns False.

Comment: sorry if this sounds dumb, but how I can I put return false after the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is that with both conditional `return` statements, you were always returning on the first iteration and ignoring the rest of the values from the list (or other iterable).

But aside from that, a few other hints that could be useful:

1. You do not need to loop by index number - just loop over the elements in the list directly.
2. To test whether an expression (here `x`) would be `True` if converted into a boolean, all you need to do is `if x:`
3. In the correct form with a single conditional `return` in the loop, it was returning `None` if no true values were found and the end of the function was reached.  But the builtin `any` returns `False` in that situation, so an explicit `return False` is needed if you want to emulate this behaviour.

```
def anys(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if x:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you @alani this code definitely looks more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Let us execute your second `any()` function line by line. 
First element of input argument is `False`.
When you check first if condition, `if bool(False) == True`, it fails.
It reaches to your second if condition.
`if bool(False) == False or len(lst) == 0`, `bool(False) == False` is true hence this `if` condition is executed and your method returns `False`.